# Vim is (seemingly) Ignoring My Configurations

Tags: vim, configuration

I've been using vim daily at work for almost 2 years now, and I've never really had any issues except for in the last two days...

My initial problem was that vim was using 8 spaces for tabs despite my settings in .vimrc. It even refused to let me reset the tab settings from within the vim instance itself. Furthermore, this problem was only happening when editing a specific file, and only while it was named a specific thing (i.e., renaming it fixed the problem). I assumed this must be due to some kind of per-file configuration that I was unaware of, and some searching led me to another post which prompted me to try the following command:

```
:so ~/.vimrc
```

This fixed my original problem, but I still don't know what caused it. I didn't do anything that I recall, it just sort of started happening as far as I can tell.

Today I deleted a swap file and all of the sudden my syntax highlighting is gone for a single file (the same one that was affected by the original issue). Again, renaming the file fixes the problem, and it running *syntax on* has no effect. This time *:so ~/.vimrc* doesn't alleviate the problem.

Does anyone have any idea what is happening here?

**Update:**
Thanks to Benoit's suggestion I found out that my vim was looking at a file in *~/.vim/view*  for some settings. When I moved this file, the issue was resolved (and vim created a new version). I'm still not 100% sure happened, but at least now I have something to look into.

Thanks Benoit!!

Comment: With what command are you executing vim (if its an alias to what does it expand)? In what type of shell? Vim version? Does your startup script or login script change paths? But im also not aware of file specific settings.

Comment: Eric - I do not use session files that I'm aware of.

Comment: RedX - I'm just running 'vim' (no special flags along with it). I'm running from a bash shell, and no path changing is going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your settings are probably modified by filetype specific files.

To know when a setting has been modified:

```
:verbose set setting?
```

for example:

```
:verb set tabstop?
:verb set expandtab?
:verb set shiftwidth?
```

Also, you could find autocmds for your file type:

```
:autocmd *.ext
```

probably some autocmd sets the file type, thus triggering `.vim` files that modify your settings.

Comment: The command to list all autocmds for a filetype is `:autocmd * *.ext`. The first argument is the event, and the second is the pattern.

Comment: Benoit - Using the :verb command you mentioned I saw that vim was looking at ~/.vim/views. When I moved the file it was referencing the file loaded up with all my normal settings. I'm still not sure exactly what happened, but now I have something to looking into. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I've kept my vim settings in `~/.exrc` for the last half-decade or so, without trouble.